# Can a .NET app be compiled to native?

Tags: .net, native, compilation, machine-code

Just wondering if a .NET app can be compiled down to native machine code ahead of time?  I'm not planning on doing so even if I could; I'm just curious.

Thanks

Comment: @Cody Thanks for the spelling corrections that will teach me not to proof read before I hit enter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use NGen to compile it ahead of time, but this still depends on the .NET framework.  Remotesoft's Salamander (a commercial app) can make a framework-less app.

Answer (score 5):

You CAN compile IL into native binaries.  There are products that do it.

The larger question is should you...

**If you want to remove all dot net dependencies to run without dot net**

Basically what these products are doing is precompiling down to the machine level (x86 usually) and then statically including all the required libraries in your exe.  That usually results in a HUGE exe.  And, more importantly, you now don't really have the runtime on your target machine.  You have a part of the runtime that the native compiler chose to incorporate.

**If you want to just get a faster JIT time**

You can also use NGen to compile it to a native binary, but you still have all the dependencies on dot net.  Target machines still need the framework, etc.

But, when you ngen you LOSE the ability for the app to auto promote up to 64 bit.  If your app is precompiled you have to force one mode.  If a user is running on a 64 bit machine your IL code would have promoted (unless you flag it not to).

The JIT time is not your biggest bottleneck in most apps.  It is the loading of the framework libraries and other related requirements.

If you really need it you can ngen within a setup app to get the current users target machine.

I also just recently learned that you cannot NGEN an app and expect it to take advantage of the CPU like you can with the JIT.  When you run NGEN is always optimizes the output for a PentiumPro for some reason, and will not take advantage of things like SSE, SSE2, etc.  So I would say that removes NGEN as a reasonable usage case.

Answer (score 1):

[ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(VS.80).aspx) can be used to 'pre-JIT' an image, so it is available on disk in native form to reduce application start up time.

Comment: BTW: Do ngen-compiled applications run slower than standard .net (despite startup-time)? I thought the JIT-compiler could do lots of optimization at runtime especially with lambda-expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Mono has an Ahead of Time (AOT) [compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT) that can emit native code.