# Changing CIL code into Native code in C#

Tags: c#, cil, native-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some way to compile a .NET application to native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702/is-there-some-way-to-compile-a-net-application-to-native-code)

When you compile a C# application, it is compiled to CIL code, to be interpreted by the framework when it is ran, but im wondering if its possible to generate a native x86 EXE file stub for my application(s).

This way it is not possible to directly open my applications in a decompiler.

P.S I cannot use a obfuscator for anything.

Comment: this is not possible, and also machine code can be decompiled, it is just harder to do...

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188006/turning-net-executable-into-native-executable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702/is-there-some-way-to-compile-a-net-application-to-native-code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778878/converting-net-app-to-x86-native-code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189757/can-a-net-app-be-complied-to-native

Comment: Voting to close this not because it's a bad question. It's a perfectly good question worthy of a +1 but there are so many duplicates already it's better just to link to those as has been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called Salmander .NET Linker but it is offered for a high price. Personally I've never used it, but I see no point in doing that. [**Offical website**](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/)

You could also try virtualizing you application using **ThinInstall** or **Xenocode Virtualization Studio**. I've used Xenocode's product to embed .NET runtime into my application and it worked great. It generates a native packed executable with your assemblies inside.

Comment: The questionned mentionned the fact that he cannot use an obfuscator for anything. That prevented me from proposing an alternative tool. I'm still thinking how to answer this question ;)

Comment: Salmander .NET Linker is a linker, not an obfuscator. I think ...

Comment: Yes but I do think that the user wanted to tell us that he do not want to use a commercial product. That's my guess. I'll give you 100 reputation points if I'm wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: [Turning .NET executable into native executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188006/turning-net-executable-into-native-executable) what you are looking for is called **AOT**

http://www.mono-project.com/AOT

Alternatively, you can check this official Microsoft technical document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(VS.71).aspx